# What are my options for an iOS 7 app with a 3D scene in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios7

I want to create an app with one of the screens being a 3D rotating object (let's say a box with a texture applied to it). Since Metal and SceneKit are not available in iOS7 and OpenGL doesn't seem to be fully supported in swift (the starter project has a lot of "Not working..." stuff in it), what are my options for creating such app without using any 3rd party frameworks like cocos2d?

Comment: With iOS 9 coming out tomorrow, do you really need to support iOS 7 in a new app?

Comment: NO. You need to focus on the iOS 9.

Comment: It needs to support iOS7, it's not my choice:)

Comment: cocos2d is built on top of OpenGL, but it is written in Objective-C as far as I know.

Comment: Also, Metal is not only not available for iOS 7: it is not supported on devices older than the iPhone 5s.